# How to Index a dataframe based on an applied function? -Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I created from a master table in SQL. That new dataframe is then grouped by type as I want to find the outliers for each group in the master table.

The function finds the outliers, showing where in the GroupDF they outliers occur. How do I see this outliers as a part of the original dataframe? Not just volume but also location, SKU, group etc.

dataframe: [HOSIERY_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cKMo.png)

Code:

```py
##Sku Group Data Frames 

grouped_skus = sku_volume.groupby('SKUGROUP')
HOSIERY_df = grouped_skus.get_group('HOSIERY')


hosiery_outliers = find_outliers_IQR(HOSIERY_df['VOLUME'])

hosiery_outliers

#.iloc[[hosiery_outliers]]
#hosiery_outliers
```

Picture to show code and output:
[image: SKU GROUP]

I know enough that I need to find the rows based on location of the index. Like Vlookup in Excel but i need to do it with in Python. Not sure how to pull only the 5, 6, 7...3888 and 4482nd place in the HOSIERY_df.

Comment: do you have an example of the dataframe so that users can provide an worked example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a list of index numbers as integers to `iloc`, which it looks like you have tried based on your commented-out code. So, you may want to make sure that `find_outliers_IQR` is returning a `list` of `int` so it will work properly with `iloc`, or convert it's output.

It looks like it's currently returning a DataFrame. You can get the index of that frame as a list like this:

```py
hosiery_outliers.index.tolist()
```

Comment: @Cyprus_Knolls - I changed the answer after rereading your question. Looks like you may have attempted to pass a dataframe to iloc instead of list of integers. Try extracting the index of that df to a list and passing that to iloc. See above

Comment: Thanks for this! This is perfect. I have to apply this to multiple groups with the master data so manually going in and search the indexes would be time consuming to say the least. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! If you don't mind, could you mark this as the answer?